# Expanding the Dictionary item from datafame column

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, python-2.7, dictionary

I have pandas dataframe with a column

I have a dataframe with a column having the value like below

```
df['dbpedia_entry']

{'dbpedia_entity': ['c'],'dbpedia_id': ['f'],'dbpedia_label': ['k'],'dbpedia_raw_result': ['a']}
{'dbpedia_entity': ['a','b'],'dbpedia_id': ['b'],'dbpedia_label': ['b'],'dbpedia_raw_result': ['a','b','c']}
```

I would like to explode the column to read dictionary inside and create four new column dbpedia_entity, dbpedia_id, dbpedia_label, dbpedia_raw_result

I have tried the pandas explode function,

```
creating dataframe from dict, df['column'].apply(pd.series)
```

But, none of them worked, How can I convert the column with dictionary value to different column?

Answer (score 1):

You may simply read your dictionary using the `from_dict` method.

```
import pandas as pd
mydict = {'dbpedia_entity': ['a','b'],'dbpedia_id': ['b'],'dbpedia_label': ['b'],'dbpedia_raw_result': ['a','b','c']}
df = pd.DataFrame()
df.from_dict(mydict, orient='index').transpose()
```

This returns:

```
    dbpedia_entity  dbpedia_id  dbpedia_label   dbpedia_raw_result
0   a               b           b               a
1   b               None        None            b
2   None            None        None            c
```

Please note that using `orient=columns` will return an error message stating that "arrays must all be same length", so you should use `orient='index'` and then transpose the output dataframe.

Comment: it works for a dictionary, but I have a column with dictionary value, then I get an error numpy.ndarry object is not callable

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Sheldon answer. If you have this initial `df`:

```
   col1                                                                                                                col2
0  val1  {'dbpedia_entity': ['a', 'b'], 'dbpedia_id': ['b'], 'dbpedia_label': ['b'], 'dbpedia_raw_result': ['a', 'b', 'c']}
1  val2                                                         {'dbpedia_entity': ['c', 'd'], 'dbpedia_label': ['e', 'f']}
```

then you can do:

```py
# apply ast.literal_eval on `col2` if they are strings:
from ast import literal_eval
df["col2"] = df["col2"].apply(literal_eval)


all_dfs = []
for c, d in zip(df["col1"], df["col2"]):
    x = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient="index").T
    x["col1"] = c
    all_dfs.append(x)

out = pd.concat(all_dfs)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
  dbpedia_entity dbpedia_id dbpedia_label dbpedia_raw_result  col1
0              a          b             b                  a  val1
1              b       None          None                  b  val1
2           None       None          None                  c  val1
0              c        NaN             e                NaN  val2
1              d        NaN             f                NaN  val2
```

Comment: I am getting the error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: @Rahul Apply `ast.literal_eval` on the column if they are strings (I've updated my answer).